# C++ main function and program

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

I am trying to get this code to run, i have tried these 2 ways but to no avail.  The aim is to receive an input using scanf and print out the statement using printf. Error message i get is the Compiler just hangs.

**Also, i am not to use any math functions such as square root or power**

**Test Cases and Expected answers**

Input1:  1.41421356237

Output1:   Area of the circle is 3.141590

Input2:  5.65

Output2:   Area of the circle is 50.143703

**Trial 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
double function(double a){
    double area;
    area = 3.14159*((a/2)*(a/2)*2);
    return area;
}

int main(void){

    double a;
    scanf("%f",a);
    double result = function(a);
    printf("Area of the circle is %f\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

**Trial 2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){


    scanf("%f",a);
    area = 3.14159*((a/2)*(a/2)*2);
    printf("Area of the circle is %f\n",area);
    return 0;
}
```

would appreciate any help, not sure why the function is not working. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Looks like the second one is missing a `double area;` and a `double a;`

Comment: if you compiler hangs on this code you probably should get a different one. Any working compiler should procude some error messages on this code. See eg [here](http://ideone.com/K8BcVK)

Comment: Change `scanf("%f",a);` to `scanf("%f",&a);`. What does this code have to do with c++ BTW? It looks like plain c code to me.

Comment: Also look into using `std::cin` and `std::cout`. They will make short work of the IO you need.

Comment: **Input1: 1.41421356237 Output1: Area of the circle is 3.141590** Whoever wrote this has intriguing ideas about geometry.

Comment: c or c++? use correct tags please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first trial you need to change your `scanf("%f",a);` line to:

```
scanf("%lf",&a);
```

because correct type specifier for double is `%lf` which stands for "long float". Also you need to send `&a` as argument because scanf expects an address and not a value. Same thing with second trial.